# Creating trigger based on LastLoginDate of Account Owner

Tags: apex, trigger, scheduled-apex, scheduled

I have to create a trigger based on **LastLoginDate** of a record owner.I have some doubts regarding use of trigger event **before update**.

1. Suppose user is not Logging in for some days , will the trigger fire?(Reason: No change in any fields, so no update)
2. In order to execute the trigger everyday can I make a formula field comparing today's date  and LastLoginDate so that everyday that field on the object get updated and in effect the trigger get fire?

Comment: If you want to execute something daily then, triggers probably are not the way to go, you should think of using scheduled batch process. Triggers are executed only when there is a insert,update or delete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have* to implement it using trigger, if possible (*Assignment by boss)

Comment: You could probably write a trigger on user object. when the LastLoginDate is changed, then do your logic. But this would not fire everyday. It would fire only when the record is changed

Comment: I do not understand why you would *have* to implement somethign using a trigger.  As @Prady pointed out, clearly this is a case for scheduled Apex.  A trigger only executes on DML operations, so it could go weeks, months, years, etc. without firing.  Trigger is not the way to go here, it's like trying to put a square peg in a round hole.  I would try to explain that to the person telling you it needs to be via trigger.

Comment: Specifically, in your option #2, formula fields are rendered in real time on record view, and do not alter the record. 

Depending on what exactly you're trying to do, it might be possible to do this declaratively with Time-Based Workflow.